# Why is the base class inherited twice even when one of them is inherited as virtual?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    class c1{
        public:
        int i;
    };
    class c2:virtual public c1{
        public:
            int j;
    };
    class c3:public c1{
        public:
            int k;
    };
    class c4:public c2,public c3{


    };

    c4 inst1;  //Its an error which indicates multiple base classes have beeen inherited
    inst1.i=34;     

}
```

My book says

> the only difference between a normal base class and a virtual one is
>   what occurs when an objects inherits the base more than once. If
>   virtual base classes are used, then only one base class is present in
>   the object. Otherwise, multiple copies will be found.

But in this program even when one of the base class is inherited as virtual why are there two copies?

Comment: It perhaps should say *"when an object inherits the base **virtually** more than once"*. That's not what hapens here.

Comment: @BoPersson i think your comment helped

Comment: Becasue it isn't inherited virtually both times.

Answer (score 4):

Inheriting virtually in one base class does not make all its sibling bases inherit virtually as well. Inheritance has to be marked virtual in all base classes that you would like to share, directly or indirectly, in the derived class.

Since you did not add `virtual` to `c3`, a C++ compiler cannot treat it inheriting `c1` as virtual inheritance.

Adding `virtual` fixes this problem:

```
class c3 : virtual public c1{
public:
    int k;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this ,"Inheriting virtually is not transitive. It has to be..."  and also on this ,"Since you did not add virtual to c3, C++ compiler cannot treat its inheriting c1 as virtual."

Comment: @rimiro "transitive" was not a right word, I thought of a different chain of inheritance when I wrote it. I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: @StoryTeller i have some question: q1.Are two c1 objects guranteed to be present inside of c4?    q2. Is c4 responsible for constructing c1 when it inherits c2.  q3. Is it c3 that is responsible for constructing c1(since there are two c1 objects) ?